# How to manage database sequences in case database is at two servers?

Tags: database, oracle11g, sequence, database-administration, data-migration

Data migration, if we are doing phase wise migration of database and DB replication we cannot go for. Then how do you think if we manually sync both the databases. How to manage sequences in this case so that both databases have Unique ID generated?

Answer (score 0):

Change the sequence definition in the 2nd database to use a different range of values.